# Where can I find the library that provides String.substring() method?

Tags: c++, arduino, porting

I'm trying to compile an Arduino project on Linux, abstracting away the hardware parts. Consider the following line:

```
int keyNumRepeat = userInputPrev.substring(6, 8).toInt();
```

It looks like Arduino uses some non-standard library, which isn't on my system:

```
hsldz_totp_lock/hsldz_totp_lock.ino:335:38: error: ‘String’ {aka ‘class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} has no member named ‘substring’; did you mean ‘substr’?
  335 |     int keyNumRepeat = userInputPrev.substring(6, 8).toInt();
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~
      |                                      substr
make: *** [Makefile:54: sim] Error 1
```

Is it available somewhere so that I could include it in my project while trying to compile? Or is it something that heavily depends on other Arduino implementation details?

Comment: Does [`string::substr`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) not meet your needs? All you'd have to do is change "substring" to "substr" like the error message is suggesting.

Comment: @DM note that there's also toInt there. I guess I could do that, but I'd first like to try looking at the actual library, otherwise I might end up with lots of IFDEFs

Comment: Arduino's code is on GitHub.

Comment: “android project”? Sure this isn’t Java code? Smells like Java.

Comment: right, that was a typo. I meant Arduino, not Android. this is C++ code, it looks like they reimplemented String.

Comment: @Taekahn, yes. It 'simulates' Processing 'language' which is Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Arduino has a custom implementation of `String`.

Since it's open source, here are the [header](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-API/blob/master/api/String.h) and [class](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-API/blob/master/api/String.cpp) files. I only skimmed through them, but they don't appear to be heavily dependent on the rest of the [Arduino core API](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-API).

That said, you may be better off replacing their implementation with standard `c++`. Especially if they're just quality-of-life improvements. The equivalent code using [`string::substr`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) and [`std::stoi`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) should be:

```c++
int keyNumRepeat = std::stoi(userInputPrev.substr(6, 8));
```